# Umbraco: Rich Text Editor Configuration

Tags: umbraco7, tinymce-3

Im trying to configure my RTE Datatype in Umbraco. For example I added the umbmediapicker to the toolbar since i want to be able to insert images into my rich text. After saving, nothing changes in my RTE toolbar, I always see the standart icons (Format, Bold, Italic, Left align, Right align, Bullet list, Numbered list and link). Does this have someting to do with the .css file or the fanoe starter pack?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that your document type property is using the correct datatype? It would also help if you provided some screenshots of the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Umbraco Fanoe starter pack use the `Grid Layout` Datatype.

To add a insert image to the Blog Post Grid (Article full width), go to Developer -> Data Types -> Grid Blogpost and there you find the Rich text editor Toolbar used in the Blogpost grid.

In Umbraco you can easily make Data Types, And customize the properties, In the Fanoe starter pack there are 3 Custom Data Types used, Grid Blogpost, Grid FrontPage and Grid TextPage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan, found  the settings, unfortunately it does not change anything in my RTE still the default icons, no image insert, no tables :(  EDIT: It was in the Grid Textpage ofc sry nvm it works, thanks again